Rendered size and Rendered aspect ratio of movie posters of TMDB API are not the same


Im new to web development.
As you can see in the image, the size of the movie posters are inconsistent and varies after entering the details page of each movie. Here my relevant codes:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import logoImage from '../assets/logo.webp';

function MovieDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?language=en-US&api_key=API-KEY`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          setMovie(response);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <body className="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full bg-[#020129] overflow-scroll">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center md:items-start w-full h-full p-8">
        {/* Poster Container with Fixed Aspect Ratio */}
        <div className="relative w-[200px] h-[300px] flex-shrink-0 px-8">
          {movie.poster_path ? (
            <img
              src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.poster_path}`}
              alt={movie.title || movie.name}
              className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-xl"
            />
          ) : (
            <div className="w-full h-full bg-gray-800 rounded-xl flex items-center justify-center">
              <span className="text-white">No Image Available</span>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        {/* Movie Details */}
        <div className="flex-shrink-0 text-white px-8 mt-8 md:mt-0">
          <a href="/" className="inline-block py-4 w-fit" title="Home">
            <img
              alt="Home"
              src={logoImage}
              className="h-8 sm:h-10 md:h-10"
            />
          </a>

          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">{movie.title || movie.name}</h1>
          <p className="mb-2">
            <strong>IMDb Score:</strong> {movie.vote_average ? movie.vote_average.toFixed(1) : "N/A"}/10
          </p>
          <p className="line-clamp-3 mb-4">{movie.overview}</p>
          <p className="mt-2"><strong>Release Date:</strong> {movie.release_date}</p>
          <p className="mt-2"><strong>Genre:</strong> {movie.genres && movie.genres.map((genre) => genre.name).join(', ')}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}

export default MovieDetails;


If you have any ideas about why this is happening or any possible solution, please share them with me.

flex-shrink-0 is not a valid TailwindCSS class, so the movie image is shrinking depending on the amount of room the movie description needs. Use shrink-0 instead.

You're right, thanks but unfortunately, using shrink-0 causes the movie posters to resize to 500x750 (the size specified by TMDB), which is too large. Can you help me with this issue?

Not sure why that would make it 500x750 when you have it specified to 200x300. I made this example that is working: https://play.tailwindcss.com/weVzyueQzX

Yes, you're right. This happened because I forgot about including the directory of this component in the tailwind.config.js file
